# Select all rows that fully intersect with the input array?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

Consider the following table

| id int | lang_codes text[] |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {eng,fre} |
| 2 | {eng} |

I need to select all the rows from the table that intersect with the input array, but only when all the items in the `lang_codes` are present in the input array, e.g.:

- if the input array contains [eng,fre,ger] then it returns all the rows
- while [eng,ger] won't return the first record, because it needs both codes to be present in the input array.

I've tried the && operand, but it returns all the rows:

```
select * from my_table where lang_codes && ARRAY['eng','ger'];
```

From the other hand @> operand, returns only when array matches fully

Comment: Are you sure? `@>` should be "contains" not "equality". Oh - do you have the arguments the wrong way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<@` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) should do the trick:

```
select * from my_table where lang_codes <@ ARRAY['eng','ger'];
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/04c34/6)